# How can I make nose tests ignore an exception?

Tags: python, nose

Under particular circumstances, I don't want my nose test to report an error as having failed and carry on with other tests, I want it to fail outright and display a stacktrace (like any other un-caught exception). Is there a (presumably nose-specific) exception type I can raise to do this?

Comment: Usually, when an exception is not caught by nose, it stops, so just raise any exception in the test.

Answer (score -1):

You can invoke nosetests with the `-x` argument.

```
-x, --stop
    Stop running tests after the first error or failure
```

Comment: That's not quite what I had in mind: I basically want a way to specify in code "the testing procedure has failed" rather than the test itself. So I don't want the first test to fail all the time, only on specific exceptions.

Comment: You could create a custom [`ErrorClass`](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/errorclasses.html) plugin. The source of the Skip plugin (onyl 50 lines) could be a reference.